# How do I display all records in a subform EXCEPT the one being displayed in the main form in Access 2010 without VBA?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010, jet

I'm working on a database in Access 2010 which stores addresses. I've carefully designed the tables so that I can store a person and an address separately and then relate them through two other tables (relationship between the people is necessary to store separately from their address as well).

I have the following tables (for this question, focus is on `PERSON` and `RELATIONSHIP`):

```
    PERSON            RELATIONSHIP           ADDR_REL             ADDR
    ------------      ------------           -----------          -----------
(PK)PERSON_ID     (FK)PERSON_ID          (FK)RELATIONSHIP_ID  (PK)ADDR_ID
    FIRST          (K)RELATIONSHIP_ID    (FK)ADDR_ID              ADDR_LINE1
    LAST              RELATIONSHIP_TYPE  (PK)ADDR_REL_ID          ADDR_LINE1
                  (PK)REL_PK                                      ...
```

**Without using VBA (if possible)**, I want to be able to display a given `PERSON` on a Form, and have a Subform which displays the *other* `PERSON`s in the matching `RELATIONSHIP`, but NOT display the original `PERSON` (whichever record is on display in the parent Form) in the subform result set.

FYI: I am able to build a solution to this in VBA myself, but it just seems like their aught to be a way to pull this off without it.

I've tried hidden fields, linked subforms, and custom Queries, but I always end up with all people in the relationship showing in the subform (or no results at all, or parameter prompts). Is there really no way to beat this without writing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the recordsource of the subform to include all the rows in the relationship except the record displayed on the main form. I'm not really sure what the logic defining "the matching relationship" looks like, but I've taken a guess below: (this is all one query but I've broken it up a bit with comments for understanding purposes - remove the comments to use it)

```
'get all persons in a given relationship
SELECT p.Person_ID, First, Last 
FROM Person p INNER JOIN Relationship r ON p.Person_ID = r.Person_ID 

'define given relationship
WHERE Relationship_ID = (
  SELECT Relationship_ID FROM Relationship 
  WHERE Person_ID = Forms(nameOfYourMainForm)!nameOfTextboxInMainFormContainingPersonID)

'and the person isnt the person displayed on the main form:
AND p.Person_ID <> Forms(nameOfYourMainForm)!nameOfTextboxInMainFormContainingPersonID;
```

Comment: `RELATIONSHIP` is simply a row with a `PERSON_ID` and a `RELATIONSHIP_ID`, and the members of a relationship are determined by matching their common `RELATIONSHIP_ID`. (I included a REL_PK for a unique identifier, but it was probably uncessesary). SO, with your solution, I need to enter the SQL directly into the RecordSource field; I do not build Query with it and then select that; correct? That is something I had not tried.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant

Comment: I was scratching my head trying to get this to work, and I finally realized I still had master and child fields linked, which filtered out anything but the exact condition which my query had already filtered out. So easy to make silly mistakes in Access! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. It has been a little while since I have used Access. It sounds like at one point you were very close.

You first create your main/master form. Then create your subform/details form. Simply drag the details form onto the master form and if your relationships are correct it will automatically set the parent / child relationship for you.

Once your parent / child relationship is set then you modify your subform/details form's record source information. if it is based on a table then then change it to a query. This can be done in the form design view.

The simple answer is, in the query builder you can hide fields. In your case probably you want to hide the Person_ID field in the sub form.

The query must contain the key fields so the parent child relationship is preserved.

Also if your subform is a form with text boxes you can also just delete the text boxes you don't want visible.

So the correct answer is yes, but did I explain it enough for you to understand?